# Algorithm to find "subpath" of a path of nodes (map/cities)

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I feel like missing something obvious or at least I feel on verge of "reveleation", but still can't get over it :)

I have a client selling transports from city A to city Z. The transport order is stored in MariadDB.
I want to help him utilize his trucks so when another client asks for transport anywhere within A to B, say C to X, I need to know :)

I started with Google maps API, but getting "cities" from the result is vague, quite complicated and expensive.
Considering client can work with "major" cities only, we set to create a graph of all major cities within the country.

**Possible solution:**
Thinking of using Djikstra's algo to determine a path within the graph, storing all the nodes of one transport order in DB and then querying any new orders against the DB to see if start+finish place falls within any other previous transport order...

If you can think of **something quicker or simple**, hit me with a link and a smile :)

*Final toughts:*
We're working with a website on nginx/php/mariadb, no substantial frameworks.
Our solutions would probably solve the problem on regional basis, but I am looking for a global solution, think worldwide transports... I searched stackoverflow questions, but I am not seeing an answer to this problem.

I am open to most ridiculous ideas, a friend of mine started talking about xpath in xml tree or regex... :)

thanks,

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning it, how about having a marketplace and having drivers grab jobs?

They know where they are going and where they are at any given time.

They also know if they are full or will have room at that part of their route.

So showing origin, destination, size, and weight for open orders would be good enough, I would think.

Comment: Not a bad approach if they're given the option to see jobs within X miles/km of their location so the pool isn't too wide of a net.

Alternatively, if you want to do this all on your side and issue out the jobs, Djikstra would be my recommendation